# Ways to advance loop prematurely

Tags: vba, excel

Other than using GOTO, are there ways to abandon a chunk of code within a loop to advance it to the next? Is GOTO an efficient way to do it in the code below?

```
Do While x < 10

    a = Int(Rnd * 100)
    b = Int(Rnd * 100)
    c = Int(Rnd * 100)

    For n = 1 To 4
        aa(i) = i * 2 + 4
        bb(i) = i * 2 + 5
        cc(i) = i * 2 + 6
    Next

    If a = b Then GoTo lastline
    If a = c Then GoTo lastline
    If b = c Then GoTo lastline

    For i = 1 To 4

        testa = (a = aa(i) Or a = bb(i) Or a = cc(i))
        If testa Then GoTo lastline

        testb = (b = aa(i) Or b = bb(i) Or b = cc(i))
        If testb Then GoTo lastline

        testc = (c = aa(i) Or c = bb(i) Or c = cc(i))
        If testc Then GoTo lastline
    Next

    Debug.Print a & ","; b & ","; c

lastline:
    x = x + 1

Loop
```

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this without using `Goto` - typically if you want to conditionally skip a block of code you'd use  `If Then`

Comment: There is no equivalent of a `continue` statement as found in many other languages.  `GoTo` would work, as would a simple `if`.

Comment: What you have is readable enough. Using `Continue` or `NextIteration` rather than `lastline` as the label could make your intentions even clearer (not that they aren't clear already).

Comment: Another option is to simply extract everything in the loop into a `Sub` or `Function`, then call it from inside the loop.  `Then GoTo lastline` becomes `Exit Sub` or `Exit Function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sake of completeness, this is what it would look like if you extracted a `Sub` to do the work.  Note that you have what I ***assume*** is a typo in your original code:

```
For n = 1 To 4
    aa(i) = i * 2 + 4    '<--- 'i'?  shouldn't these be 'n'?
    bb(i) = i * 2 + 5
    cc(i) = i * 2 + 6
Next
```

Since you are using `i` as the loop counter later, it will *always* be whatever it was coming into the loop the first time through, and 4 every time after that.  My guess is that this isn't what you intended.

That out of the way... extracted `Sub`:

```
Private Sub WhateverYoureDoing(aa As Variant, bb As Variant, cc As Variant)
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long

    a = Int(Rnd * 100)
    b = Int(Rnd * 100)
    c = Int(Rnd * 100)

    'Assuming this should be 'i' instead of 'n' as the loop count.
    For i = 1 To 4
        aa(i) = i * 2 + 4
        bb(i) = i * 2 + 5
        cc(i) = i * 2 + 6
    Next

    If a = b Then Exit Sub
    If a = c Then Exit Sub
    If b = c Then Exit Sub

    For i = 1 To 4
        If a = aa(i) Or a = bb(i) Or a = cc(i) Then Exit Sub
        If b = aa(i) Or b = bb(i) Or b = cc(i) Then Exit Sub
        If c = aa(i) Or c = bb(i) Or c = cc(i) Then Exit Sub
    Next

    Debug.Print a & ","; b & ","; c
End Sub
```

Calling code:

```
Do While x < 10
    WhateverYoureDoing aa, bb, cc
    x = x + 1
Loop
```

Note that you can simplify this code tremendously.  For example, this...

```
a = Int(Rnd * 100)
b = Int(Rnd * 100)
c = Int(Rnd * 100)
'...
If a = b Then GoTo lastline
If a = c Then GoTo lastline
If b = c Then GoTo lastline
```

...can be simply:

```
Do
    a = Int(Rnd * 100)
    b = Int(Rnd * 100)
    c = Int(Rnd * 100)
Loop While a <> b And a <> c And b <> c
```

Comment: this is very helpful and very clean. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would just wrap the part which might be skipped with an if statement.
The second For loop can also be exited early with Exit For.  Doing this avoids using GoTo.  I haven't tested the code below, but it should illustrate the concept.

```
Do While x < 10
    a = Int(Rnd * 100)
    b = Int(Rnd * 100)
    c = Int(Rnd * 100)
    For n = 1 To 4
        aa(i) = i * 2 + 4
        bb(i) = i * 2 + 5
        cc(i) = i * 2 + 6
    Next
    If Not a = b Or Not a = c Or Not b = c Then
        For i = 1 To 4
            testa = (a = aa(i) Or a = bb(i) Or a = cc(i))
            testb = (b = aa(i) Or b = bb(i) Or b = cc(i))
            testc = (c = aa(i) Or c = bb(i) Or c = cc(i))
            If testa Or testb Or testC Then
                Exit For
            Else
                If i = 4 Then
                    Debug.Print a & ","; b & ","; c
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
    x = x + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks @DGilledge.

Comment: This runs the risk doing an eternal loop.  It will only increment on the else of the first if and true on the second.  If it makes it to the debug.print it will not increment and the x.  though we are somewhat safe in that the numbers change and eventually it will satisfy one of the other two possibilities and increment. You may want to move the increment outside the first IF so it fires every time the for loop ends.  Then you can remove the one inside the for loop.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out.  I've edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated you would use IFs to skip when false:

```
Do While x < 10

    a = Int(Rnd * 100)
    b = Int(Rnd * 100)
    c = Int(Rnd * 100)

    For n = 1 To 4
        aa(i) = i * 2 + 4
        bb(i) = i * 2 + 5
        cc(i) = i * 2 + 6
    Next

    If Not a = b Or Not a = c Or Not b = c Then

        For i = 1 To 4

            testa = (a = aa(i) Or a = bb(i) Or a = cc(i))
            If Not testa Then
                testb = (b = aa(i) Or b = bb(i) Or b = cc(i))
                If Not testb Then
                    testc = (c = aa(i) Or c = bb(i) Or c = cc(i))
                    If Not testc Then
                        Debug.Print a & ","; b & ","; c
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next

    End If

    x = x + 1

Loop
```

Comment: Thank you Scott. Bad that I did not use OR to cut the first 3 IFs to 1 - so amateur! I am hoping to get through the first test (a, b, c)  and if TRUE, avoid testing the array variables completely which can get very lengthy. And the same within the loop, hoping to end it early and move the loop on as soon as I see a TRUE without wasting time on the rest of the FOR loop. I thought about using EXIT FOR which will allow me to head towards LOOP, but I do not know enough to not use GOTO for the first test of (a, b, c) among themselves.

Comment: @JohnColeman, thanks for the tip, very helpful, didn't think about editing friendliness!

Comment: @Comintern, is it considered best or better practice to use sub or function for this sort of situation? Been very lazy with passing variables.

Comment: @AlexK, yes, I was very disappointed to have the editor refusing CONTINUE FOR with my first attempt. Admitted I did not realise GOTO still exists even with the disappearance of line numbers!

Comment: Sorry @ScottCraner Please ignore my last comment. Your nested IFs do exactly that. Apologies for not reading the answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Exit` in a lot of different ways including `Exit For` to get out of your `For...Next` Loop.

[Here is the `Exit` MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2at9t47.aspx)

> **Exit For**
>
> Immediately exits the For loop in which it appears. Execution continues with the statement following the Next statement. Exit For can be used only inside a For...Next or For Each...Next loop. When used within nested For loops, Exit For exits the innermost loop and transfers control to the next higher level of nesting.